Unable to Access Latest Telegram Channel Post via Telegram Widget
I'm trying to embed a Telegram channel feed on my website using the official Telegram widget. When I specify a specific post number, it works perfectly, but when I use the "latest" keyword to show the most recent post, nothing is displayed.
Here’s the working code that shows a specific post:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Telegram Widget</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="telegram-widget-container">
  <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?19" data-telegram-post="Fox_News_Welcome/5735" data-width="100%"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>

However, when I use "latest" instead of the post number, like this:
<div class="telegram-widget-container">
  <script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?19" data-telegram-post="Fox_News_Welcome/latest" data-width="100%"></script>
</div>

The widget doesn't display anything, and there are no errors in the console.
Has anyone experienced this issue with the "latest" keyword in Telegram's widget? Is there a workaround, or am I missing something in the configuration?
